# how to create folder in android/app/src/main with expo eas?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, eas, expo-file-system

I'm working on to make android application with react-native and expo.
I'm using library to render some 3d object.

**.obj format file need to be in android/app/src/main/assets to use that library.**

I can load pictures something like .jpg, .png but .obj.

I don't control the android folder with git because it creates too much different files every time. (git ignored)
expo-file-system library doesn't save the file in exact address that I want(android/app/src/main/assets).
If there is a any way to save file with that library, please tell me.

So I created assets folder after expo build android folder.
Then I put .obj file manually(copy and paste) with my self.
Do I have to create folder manually whenever expo builds android folder?

And even I put my file in assets folder, the file is not showing after eas build .....
Please help

Comment: you can make android and iOS folder using "expo eject".

Comment: I know, I mean should I have to copy and paste obj file after expo eject everytime ; (

Comment: do you try https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/asset/

Comment: Yes but it only save in android file system(file:///data/user/0/com.hhj0988a.jockey/files/assets/file.obj) or have file in cached memory not in android/app/src/main/assets. Requiring .obj format keep generating error eventhough I put this "defaultConfig.resolver.assetExts.push("obj");" in metro.config.js